# Access body in request as params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a request that is coming from an API.

The request is the body as raw text in json format

Something like this:

```
{
    "login": "my_login",
    "password": "ABcd1234"
}
```

How do I access the params in rails? If the params are in the url itself, they all come in params[]. But when it comes in the body, the only way I found is:

```
prms = JSON.parse( request.body.read )
```

and then:

```
prms["login"]
```

Is there a built in rails way to do it?

Comment: Why you are not getting values as `params` in the first place(in the controller's action)?

Because `ActionController::Paramters` for > rails 5 or `Hash` for rails < 5 you will get everything coming in API will be accessible by `params`.

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understands you. The format is coning from an outside API. I need to make params out of this format. That's the question.

Comment: Lets discuss the problem here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239882/room-for-ajay-barot-and-noam-b